# How do reduce this expression

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I spent quite some time trying to figure out why my answer was wrong, only to discover that it was right, just simplified in a way a very poor way in Mathematica:

```
vs1 = (1. (3.3 + 1. I4 R1 + 1. I4 R2) Rs)/(1. R1 + 1. R2 + 1. Rs)
vin1= (3.3*R1+vs1*R2)/(R1+R2)//Together//FullSimplify
```

which results in $vin1$:
$$=\frac{3.3 (1. R1^2 + 1. R1 R2 + 1. R1 Rs + 1. R2 Rs + 0.30303 I4 R1 R2 Rs + 0.30303 I4 R2^2 Rs)}{((R1 + R2) (1. R1 + 1. R2 + 1. Rs))}$$

This can be reduced to: $$vin1 = \frac{(3.3 R1+3.3 Rs+1. I4 R2 Rs)}{(1. R1+1. R2+1. Rs)} ,$$
but I can't get Mathematica there.  I've tried //FullSimplify, //Together, //Cancel //Factor, etc. and I cannot figure out how to have Mathematica  fully simplify the resulting expression for vin1.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is

```
N@Simplify@Rationalize@vin1
(* (0.1 (33. R1 + (33. + 10. I4 R2) Rs))/(R1 + R2 + Rs) *)
```

what you are looking for?  Finite precision numbers may be confusing `Simplify`.

Comment: Thank you!! Can you explain what exactly this statement is doing (and why it works)?  Thanks again!

Comment: @jrive, `Rationalize` converts all decimal numbers to rational numbers, after which `Simplify` performs the desired simplification.  Finally, `N` coverts the rational numbers back to decimal numbers.  Omit `N@`, if you are satisfied with an answer containing only rational numbers.  In my experience, Mathematica generally works better with rational numbers.  Thanks for accepting my answer.

Comment: I wonder now if all my struggles with simplifying results in the past could have been avoided by rationalizing!!  Thanks!